# How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

How can map the values of the firestore array as shown in the image using Python. It contains the array "ingredients" of the documents from the collection called training_dataset.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSdAt.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of that document specifically, you could do

```
training_dataset_doc = db.collection(u'training_dataset').where(u'id', u'==', u'0Ky1FzKjoM08kN6fkYpn').get().to_dict()
```

Then, you will have your desired list of dicts in `training_dataset_doc['ingredients']`